# marginalising probability with itself

Tags: probability

I am wondering if the following statement is true:

$$P[f(X,Y)]=\sum_x P[f(X,Y),X=x]$$

where $X$ and $Y$ are any two independent r.v. and $f()$ is any arbitrary function of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: you mean $P[f(X,Y)\in A]=\sum_x P[f(X,Y)\in A,X=x]$ for every event $A$?

Comment: Yes. This is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that $X$  is a discrete random variables (since there is a sum on $x$). What you want is called the [Law of Total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) ;if we have a countable partition $B_n$ on the sample space then $$P(A) = \sum_n P(A \cap B_n)$$

In this case $B_x = \{X = x\}$ is a partition of the sample space, we can write

$$P(f(X,Y) \in A) = \sum_x P(f(X,Y) \in A, X = x)  = \sum_x P(f(x,Y) \in A)$$

Notice that we don't need $X$ and $Y$ to be independent.

Also note that if $X$ is *not* discrete, then the partition $B_x = \{X = x\}$ is *not* countable, therefore the whole thing breaks down. (Also, $\sum_x$ don't really mean anything if you're summing on a uncountable numbers of $x$)

There are no restrictions on $Y$ though